# How to rotate the TextBlock in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Textblock in XAML code

```
   <TextBlock Text="^" Margin="0,16,0,0" TextAlignment='Center' RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding RotateAngel}"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
```

And the text block is a content of a GridViewHeader have a click event but when I try `arrow.RenderTransform` But there aren't any property to set the rotation

Comment: What's `RotateAngel`, and why not set that?

Comment: Yep. StackOverflow is great in answering wrong questions. The answer should be: don't do that in code-behind, unless you really know what you do. But then you wouldn't ask that question ;)

Answer (score -1):

> ...but when I try `arrow.RenderTransform` But there aren't any property to set the rotation

Since you have set the `RenderTransform` property to a `TransformGroup`, you could cast it to `TransformGroup` and then access the `RotateTransform`:

```
TransformGroup tg = arrow.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;
if (tg != null)
{
    RotateTransform rt = tg.Children[0] as RotateTransform;
    if (rt != null)
        rt.Angle = 180;
}
```

Comment: @QuanVN: Did you try this or what is your actual question...?

Comment: No, I don't  mean your answer wrong but I find a easier way to do

Comment: Remove the question or accept the answer or post your own answer then...